# Fastest way to add value to every element of vector<int>

Tags: c++

```
vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4};
```

I want to add 2 to every element of vector v1 without using loop and after execution the vector v1 must be
v1{3,4,5,6}

Comment: What have you tried? Is the vector always 4 elements in size?

Comment: If it is always 4 elements in size your best bet will probably be to use SIMD intrinsics.

Comment: Finding the fastest can be an expensive undertaking and usually  doesn't port all that well. Usually Fast enough should be all you need.

Comment: @vandench, Compilers are pretty good at adding SIMD instructions for you these days. I'd prefer readable code if the compiler's going to do it anyway.

Comment: why "without using loop" ? Because loops are slow? It's not the loop that makes it slow, but the fact that you have to do something for every element.

Comment: When you say "without a loop", do you mean an explicit loop like `for`? You could call an algorithm instead of a loop, but it will still go through every element in your range.

Comment: One problem is that unless you repeat each instruction, you are going to need a loop at some point.

Comment: @chris While compilers have definitely improved a lot, they can still be quite bad at vectorizing some code. If performance truly matters (which I doubt it does in this case) manual vectorization is always the way to go. Also SIMD code really isn't that hard to read. The intrinsics are pretty self explanatory in what they do for the most part. [Here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1erdEbrG7) is short example for this question which very easily reduces the number of instructions.

Comment: Research SIMD instructions.  There may be an instruction that will add a single (constant) value to an array.  However, the processor may loop here, so that may not be acceptable.

Comment: There must be a loop somewhere, whether it's explicit or not. Sequential access is very, very CPU friendly. I would just do a loop;

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fast way without using loops:

```
v1[0] += 2;
v1[1] += 2;
v1[2] += 2;
v1[3] += 2;
```

The fastest way is the one that you have measured to be the fastest on your system.

Comment: if there would be 1000 elements then what would I do

Comment: @NalinMahajan, Use a loop or generate the source code in Python. There's really a good chance the former is going to work well for you. It's not like the compiler can't see through basic loops.

Comment: Since you said not to use loops, you would have to repeat this example for 1000 elements.  What's the reason for not looping?

Comment: @NalinMahajan If there would be 1000 elements, I would use a loop. In fact, I would use a lop for 4 elements as well. But you asked for no loops, so that's what you got.

Comment: There must be a loop somewhere, whether it's explicit or not. Sequential access is very, very CPU friendly. I would just do a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the number of elements is hard-coded and you are willing to code the increment of each element individually, then a loop is required, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> v1;
...
for(int &elem){
    elem += 2;
}
```

But, you don't have to code the loop manually, you can let the standard library handle it for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> v1;
...
std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v1.begin(),
    [](int elem){ return elem + 2; }
);
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> v1;
...
std::for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
    [](int &elem){ elem += 2; }
);
```